# Dialogflow Account Linking Authorization Code Flow. How to force re-link account

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

**Setup:**
I have an agent that is integrated with google assistant and successfully links to an Account using Authorization Code Flow.
I can make api calls with auth token returned in user object from the initial account linking flow.
Account linking was enabled using check box to require account linking before using agent.
[image]

I am not sure if it happens normally after some time has passed or after I revoke token access. But a verification api call will return 401 unauthorized.
[image]

The user object still has `VERIFIED` status but the token is not valid.
[image]

Currently I am just returning to user telling them to try again later and it eventually gets settled I am assuming after token expiration. I want to solve this sooner in the conversation the way initial account linking is done. This is preventing me from debugging.

**QUESTION:**
Any way to trigger account linking flow from fulfillment? Or force verification status to unverified?
Even a way to clear cached data to allow re-auth would be helpful?

**EDIT**
Adding validation call. Simple call.

```
  try {
    return response = await instance.get('/oauth2/validate', { headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}` } });
  } catch (error) {
    _handleError(conv, error);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more information on how you setup your verification call? Is it through the [regular OAuth flow](https://developers.google.com/assistant/identity/oauth-concept-guide) or some other part? Are you sending an [UnauthorizedError](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/blob/9f8c250a385990d28705b3658364c74aa3c19adb/src/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.ts#L530) inline?

Comment: It really has nothing to do with validation call. I make the call because it is simple and proves connection is working.
I edited question to include validation call.

Comment: At this point Dialog flow blew everything up and removed integration settings to do this. Everything needs converted to Actions on Google and I moved away from Actions on Google because it was difficult to work with and did not handle required app linking correctly.